# Time conversion from 24hrs to 12hrs

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am getting the time like 13.40, but i need to convert it to 1.40.. any one know, what is the best way to do this. i am using jquery to make time.

my code is :

```
var time = new Date(myDate);
var hours = time.getHours();

alert(hours);
```

Comment: That's not jQuery, it's just JavaScript.

Comment: @Cory: Agreed, retagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
hours = hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours;
```

Comment: Actually, `hours = hours % 12` is a bit simpler ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
if (hours > 12) {
  hours -= 12;
}
```

Um, as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `modulus` operator, `%` for this

```
var input = "13.40"; 
var atoms = input.split(".");
var output = atoms[0] % 12 + "." + atoms[1];
output; // "1.40";
```

If you want to prefix with 0 then you can do this

```
var output = ("0" + atoms[0] % 12).slice(-2) + "." + atoms[1];
output; // "01.40";
```

If you want AM/PM as a suffix

```
var output = ("0" + atoms[0] % 12).slice(-2) + "." + atoms[1] + 
     (atoms[0] < 13 ? " AM" : " PM");
output; // "01.40 PM";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator for this:

```
var hours = time.getHours() % 12
```

Comment: right it is modulo. Thanks!
Btw this solution does not really works because 12:00 should be 12m and 24 should be 12pm.